# Find XML node based on attribute with Xpath & then update value of it's child

Tags: php, xml

Best / Most efficient way of achieving this? DOMDocument? Xpath? Mixture of both?

```
<currencies>
  <currency id="USD">
    <title>United States Dollar</title>
    <loc>American Samoa, British Indian Ocean Territory, Caribbean Netherlands, Ecuador, El Salvador, Guam, Haiti, Marshall Islands, Micronesia, Northern Mariana Islands, Palau, Panama, Puerto Rico, Timor-Leste, Turks and Caicos Islands, United States, U.S. Virgin Islands, Barbados (as well as Barbados Dollar), Bermuda (as well as Bermudian Dollar), Zimbabwe</loc>
    <rate>1.2723</rate>
    <timestamp>1325962378</timestamp>
  </currency>
</currencies>
```

I need to access the currency node based on the attribute 'id' which I've done like so:

```
$xml->xpath('//currency[id="'.$currId.'"]');
```

**How do I now access the child node called "rate" and edit it's value before then saving the file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath was almost correct; you were just missing an `@` symbol.  Here is a solution that works with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML):

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//currency[@id="'.$currId.'"]'); // returns an array
$nodes[0]->rate = $new_rate; // set the first element's rate to the rate stored
                             // in $new_rate
$xml->asXML($filename);  // save the XML to the file $filename
```